# How to keep max checkpoints with some criteria?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to keep only a number of checkpoints in TensorFlow during training because of the disk limit. `CheckpointManager` has a `max_to_keep` argument, but by default, it keeps the newest checkpoints.

Is there a way to keep a limited number of checkpoints according to some criteria, say the validation loss, easily in TensorFlow? Surely I can write the code myself, but it would be good to make the use of `CheckpointManage`r, and just in case there's anything written already that I've neglected.

P.S. I noticed the ModelCheckpoint but my model is not of type `tf.keras.models.Model` so, unfortunately, cannot make use of that feature.

Answer (score 0):

`ModelCheckpoint` is a Callback subclass. You can modify the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.9.0/keras/callbacks.py#L1162-L1599) to adapt it to your use case. In particular, you can focus on the constructor and the `_save_model` method. This can be used as a starting point to write your own code.